# sqlite: lookup-or-replace

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I would like to use sqlite (using Java JDBC, not sure if that matters) to add or replace a new row to a database, and return the autogenerated ID of the row, and I'm not sure how to do this efficiently/cleanly.

table definition has >= 3 columns:

- autogenerated integer `ID`
- unique key string (let's call it `key`)
- other metadata

I can think of two general approaches:

1. `SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE key = ?`
2. If there's no match, INSERT a new row, and repeat step #1 to get the autogenerated ID

or

1. `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable (key, metadata) VALUES (?, ?)`
2. `SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE key = ?`

What should I do? Not sure if either approach is an atomic transaction. (well, the first isn't, not sure about the 2nd)

---

edit: I just tried the INSERT OR REPLACE approach, and it "works", except that it also replaces the ID with a new one, which is not what I want to have happen. I want to keep the existing ID.

Comment: OMG - Java is a perfectly valid tag. There may be Java framework specific solutions (e.g. hibernate).

Comment: @cyberkiwi: The question doesn't remotely relate to java -- entirely SQL.  Doesn't change the fact you rollback my edits to make the question more readable.  You have the power to edit questions -- start using it responsibly and grow up.

Comment: @OMG - the question states, I quote `using Java JDBC..replace a new row to a database, and return the autogenerated ID of the row`. There are Java framework solutions for this. Where do you get the `"not related to Java"` bit from.  It was readable as-is unless you cannot discern the gaps and the "or" in between

Comment: look, I appreciate the help @OMG Ponies, but I agree w/ @cyberkiwi and you don't have to add extra formatting. It's fairly clear as it is, IMHO

Comment: @cyber: That's why you need to erase all my edits?  You're only here because I was.

Comment: @OMG `You're only here because I was` - come again?

Comment: With respect, you are not the community.  I'm sorry that cyber has decided to make your question a platform to attack me on.

Comment: look you two, please quit it.

Comment: "Shame on you" ??? I'm not very familiar with JDBC+SQLite, that's why I asked the question. If you have suggestions, by all means, post them -- I upvote anything that's helpful.

Comment: ok, noted. It would have been helpful to point out `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`, which I didn't know about... I'm also not sure how a roundtrip SELECT + [look-at-the-results] + INSERT works with transactions -- I've used transactions w/ MySQL before, but only as a write-only approach, e.g. an INSERT statement followed by a DELETE statement, where the server is doing all the work, not where the client is reading the values in the middle of the transaction to decide what step to do in the next part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a PreparedStatement you can return the generated key for an insert so there is no need to run a select statement after a insert just to get the key.

To do this:

- When you prepare the statement, use
  the method that allows you specify it
  to return the generated keys.
- After you run the update call "getGeneratedKeys()" on the statement object.

Comment: could you give an example? I looked at PreparedStatement and it says executeUpdate() returns an int which is the row count, not a generated key. Also I'm not sure what to do if it's an update and not an insert (I have to handle both cases).

Comment: When you prepare the statement, use the method that allows you specify  it to return the generated keys.  After you run the update call "getGeneratedKeys()" on the statement object.

Comment: ah! I didn't see that method. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: hey, that works great (suggest you put `getGeneratedKeys()` into your answer) -- except an INSERT OR REPLACE replaces the old autogenerated ID with a new one :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is a SQLITE function for getting the last inserted auto id

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Not sure if it works for updates though